# Disable access to other preferences in air application while native window is open

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, air, desktop-application

I have an air application. Clicking the application menu item opens a native window. Just like in other applications, I want that while the native window is open, access to other preferences in the application (like close application etc) should be disabled.
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable all access to the main application? Or just specific parts?

Comment: all access main application or in other words inactive until native windows will close.For example in photoshop or flash if you click in menu File > New  opening a new native window in application and disabled all access parent window until this native window will close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any easy way of doing this. The best I can think of is to listen for the DEACTIVATE event, prevent it, and then manually reactivate the window. Some code:

```
var args:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
var subWindow:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(args);
subWindow.activate();
subWindow.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, onDeactivate);

private function onDeactivate(event:Event):void
{
    event.preventDefault();
    NativeWindow(event.target).activate();
}
```

This will ensure that this subWindow always retains focus until it is closed.

There are two differences that I can see between this method and typical application behavior for this type of subwindow.

1) The parent window can be dragged around (for some reason this does not dispatch a DEACTIVATE event)

2) Usually the subwindow should kind of "flicker" and plays an alert sound to indicate that it must be dealt with before further actions can be made (this is the the behavior for other applications on Windows 7 at least; I am not sure about other OS's).

For the dragging problem you should be able to have the parent window listen for the MOVING event and preventDefault() whenever the subwindow is active.

I don't see any good way of replication the behavior of 2. You can have the subwindow `notifyUser(NotificationType.INFORMATIONAL)` in the DEACTIVATE event but it's not the same thing that other applications do.

Comment: Thank you very much, your code explains very cleary to solve of my primary importance problem on my application and even more than just

Comment: Funnily enough this is the exact solution I used to resolve the same problem I had less than a week ago. I'm a bit disappointed that AS3 doesn't have a built-in property for this, similar to `alwaysInFront`, since file selection dialogues do this automatically (along with the flicker and alert sound). Still, this manual solution is pretty much perfect anyway.